# How could this image be reproduced with MMA?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, generative-art

It is assumed that this image was obtained by computer-graphics, any idea to reproduce it, as I show it, thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why not email the owner of that web site to get the equations?

Comment: a possibility, but you can't understand the link, it is just covered by the picture

Comment: What have YOU tried?

Comment: It sure looks like www.fegovi.com.  What was the website from which you obtained the picture?

Comment: @rpujadas: The website is: http://www.fegovi.com/, the image is http://www.fegovi.com/math/math084g.htm, the owner has an email there.

Comment: the truth first I tried to get the formulas that form that figure, then I tried with some curves like sine and cosine, but I do not know how to give color, I am a beginner in MMA and I do examples to learn.

Comment: I read it as ñegovi.com, I will send you an email now. Anyway someone could give me an example of how to vary the color as the graph is drawn.

Comment: To mimick the *style* of the image, `ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2t],Cos[2.5t],Cos[3t]},{t,0,10},Axes->False,Boxed->False,ColorFunction->"Rainbow",Background->Black]` may be helpful.  Of course, the exact functions and color function that make *that* plot are different.  Finding them precisely is a challenging task

Answer (score 5):

A possible way.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x - y, x + y, Sin[x*y]}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, 
  Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][x]], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 36], 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, Background -> Black, 
  PlotPoints -> 80] /. 
 Polygon[a_] :> {Thickness[Large], 
   Line[a, VertexNormals -> Automatic, VertexColors -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your selfless contributions, they help me a lot.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[{x - y, x + y, Sin[x*y]}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][x]], 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 36], 
 Background -> Black, Mesh -> {40, 60}, PlotStyle -> None] /. {(VertexColors -> None) -> VertexColors -> Automatic}`

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: I interpret these sorts of questions as a request for brainstorming.  Here's how one might tackle the problem of reverse-engineering the colors: let's get every distinct color of the image, and try to identify a simple function to reproduce the non-black colors

```
img=ImageTake[#, Last@ImageDimensions@# - 200] &@
 Import["http://www.fegovi.com/math/math084g.jpg"]
```

The `ImageTake` removed the gray logos.

```
cols=Union@Flatten[ImageData@RemoveAlphaChannel@img, 1]
```

Now we have every distinct color of the image in a list, about 130k of them.  Let's `ListPointPlot3D` them in RGB space, a `RandomSample` of 10k of them

[image: cols]

It looks like these fall on a few planes.  Perhaps someone more adept then I can compute the multiple planes of best fit.

Comment: thank you for your selfless contributions, they help me a lot.